# Testing that the API request is working golang

Tags: json, csv, go, testing

I am trying to add tests to my golang project. My program is saving JSON data into csv file. What I do is displaying my data on the screen (see the comment `// STDOUT`) and use a pipe that automatically creates the format file I want: `go run main.go > file.csv`, for example here I save the data into a csv file named file.csv

To be more clear, here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

type People struct {
    Name string
    Craft string
}

type General struct {
    People []People
    Number int
    Message string
}

func main() {
    // Reading data from JSON File  
    response, err := http.Get("http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("The Http request failed with error %s\n", err)
    }

    data,_ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    //fmt.Println(string(data))
    // Unmarshal JSON data
    var general General
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &general)
    var header []string
    header = append(header, "Number")
    header = append(header, "Message")
    header = append(header, "Name")
    header = append(header, "Craft")
    fmt.Println(strings.Join(header, ","))
    for _, obj := range general.People {    
        var record []string
        record = append(record, strconv.Itoa(general.Number), general.Message)
        record = append(record, obj.Name, obj.Craft)
        fmt.Println(strings.Join(record, ",")) // STDOUT 
        record = nil
    }
}
```

So on my screen I obtain this output as expected:

```
Number,Message,Name,Craft
6,success,Christina Koch,ISS
6,success,Alexander Skvortsov,ISS
6,success,Luca Parmitano,ISS
6,success,Andrew Morgan,ISS
6,success,Oleg Skripochka,ISS
6,success,Jessica Meir,ISS
```

So I am wondering how I can test if this output is correctly displaying the datas I expect.

I tried to write a `main_test.go` file but I can't find out how to code it correctly.

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
)

func TestGetEntries(t *testing.T) {
    response, err := http.Get("http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    // I don't know how to deal with this part:
    rr := httptest.NewRecorder()
    handler := http.HandlerFunc(main)
    handler.ServeHTTP(rr, req)
    if status := rr.Code; status != http.StatusOK {
        t.Errorf("handler returned wrong status code: got %v want %v",
            status, http.StatusOK)
    }

    // Check the response body is what we expect.
    // For example I want to test the first line:
    expected := `6,success,Christina Koch,ISS`
    if rr.Body.String() != expected {
        t.Errorf("handler returned unexpected body: got %v want %v",
            rr.Body.String(), expected)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: [JSONLines are better than CSV](http://jsonlines.org/examples/)

Comment: Write objects to a "master list", then print the whole list to the stdout. Then you can test against the list contents

Comment: Also, tests shouldn't rely on external services. Create fake responses with real data + some expected HTTP error response.

Comment: *Unit* tests shouldn't rely on external services. *Integration* tests should. OP didn't specify which this is.

Comment: I don't understand how you can do that.

Comment: Wow a test question, I loved! :D

Comment: I believe this may be useful for you about how test this type of thing https://github.com/roger-russel/fasthttp-router-middleware/blob/master/docs/examples/group/main_test.go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me warning that I may like tests a little too much, normal people usually don't go too far with it.

Testing something that will be printed directed into stdout in main is something that I usually try to avoid, it will be more easy to test if the content was returned from a function before print it to stdout.

There are sometimes that I really want my test coverage the main as well into this case is possible to use a test function prefixed with "Example" it is a poor solution but is quite simple to use.

**main.go**

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main(){
   fmt.Println("Hello World")
}
```

**main_test.go**

```
package main
func ExampleMain(){
   main()
   // Output:
   // Hello World
}
```

With your code the "Example" should be:

```
package main
func ExampleMain(){
   main()
   // Output:
   // Number,Message,Name,Craft
   // 6,success,Christina Koch,ISS
   // 6,success,Alexander Skvortsov,ISS
   // 6,success,Luca Parmitano,ISS
   // 6,success,Andrew Morgan,ISS
   // 6,success,Oleg Skripochka,ISS
   // 6,success,Jessica Meir,ISS
}
```

It is an easy way to test but is a little hard to keep it updated, so I don't like it so much.

I would prefer something more flexible like this:
**main.go**

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    txt := helloWorld()

    fmt.Println(txt)
}

func helloWorld() string {
    return "Hello World"
}
```

**main_test.go**

```
package main

import "testing"

func Test_helloWorld(t *testing.T) {
    tests := []struct {
        name string
        want string
    }{
        {
            name: "A simple Test",
            want: "Hello World",
        },
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            if got := helloWorld(); got != tt.want {
                t.Errorf("helloWorld() = %v, want %v", got, tt.want)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

It is preferable to not request external services when possible on your tests, of course, if you feel that is better request it into your test for any reason that you know then that's ok too, but if you feel that would be better be a mock it request and don't know how I would be glade to sugest some ways to do it.